# code issue with developing a sentiment analysis scoring model

Tags: r, analysis, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do some sentiment analysis on twitter data. I have a dictionary (afinn_list) which is something like below

1102. good 5
1103. bad -5
1104. awesome 6

I have been able to generate a character variable which contains the location of each matched word. Now I want to generate a score variable which will contain the corresponding score for these matches. I am having hard time coming up with a for loop logic.

> class(afinn_list)

[1] "data.frame"

> vPosMatches <- match(words, afinn_list$word)
>
> vPosMatches

[1]   NA   NA   NA   NA 1104   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 1836   NA

I am sorry if the question is too naive. I am just trying to learn sentiment analysis using R.

Answer (score 0):

Sentiment analysis is a complex task. Assuming you have clean up your data from twitter and storing it as 1 word in each cell, I guess what you are lacking now is score your cleaned up data in `words` with your scoring "dictionary" `afinn_list`.

Assuming that your words is a afinn_list looks like this

```
dictionary <-data.frame(grade=c('bad','not good', 'ok', 'good','very good'), score=1:5))
#     grade score
1       bad     1
2  not good     2
3        ok     3
4      good     4
5 very good     5
```

and your mock_data ( clean up data from twitter) is

```
mock_data<-data.frame(data=rep(x=c('good','bad','rubbish','hello','very good'),10))
#       data
1      good
2       bad
3   rubbish
4     hello
5 very good
6      good
```

You will do a merge between 2 data frame. In SQL world, it will be an left outer join . In R, it is impletemed with the function `merge` and providing the column you wish to join by and `all.x=True`

Hence your code will look like this

```
   merge(mock_data, dictionary, by='data', all.x=TRUE)
```

I hope this answer you question.

Cheers